# Shopify keep user logged in and session never expire

Tags: session, cookies, shopify, liquid

We want to keep user logged in or give them the option (like a checkbox) to keep the session up, and prevent expiry.

Answer (score 2):

That is something Shopify does not provide. A customer session will always expire, and that allows Shopify to clean up any inventory they may have set aside in their session, among other things.

If you mean a User of your App, they never login anyway, so what exactly are you speaking of? They get granted authorization via oAuth and JWT tokens, not logging in/logging out.